# Modificar htacess para permitir download de arquivos xml

Tags: php, javascript, xml, htaccess

Tenho o seguinte código em meu arquivo ".htacess"

```
RewriteEngine On
#Options All -Indexes

## ROUTER WWW Redirect.
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

## ROUTER HTTPS Redirect
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ROUTER URL Rewrite
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Sistema/index.php?route=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Porém quando eu clico no botão para fazer download de um arquivo xml que está no diretório do sistema eu recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
Failed opening required 'code/backup.xml' (include_path='C:\xampp_2020\php\pear') in C:\xampp_2020\htdocs\Sistema\index.php
```

Já tentei modificar o php.ini e não funcionou, por isso acredito que o problema seja no meu htacess

Comment: Acredito que o problema não esteja no .htacess e sim na URL absoluta para acesso do seu backup.xml. Já que usa xampp, é interessante vocẽ criar uma variável gobal chamada $url que recebe o endereço da sua aplicação, exemplo: $url = 'localhost/projeto/';      e toda vez que for utilizar é só colocar um $url."code/backup.xml" que provavelmente ele encontrará o arquivo.

Comment: Talles testei na aplicação e funcionou sim, muito obrigado! Eu não havia mexido com htaccess antes e acreditava que o problema estava nele fazendo algum tipo de "bloqueio" ao download de arquivos da minha aplicação

Comment: Vou deixar abaixo para fim de documentação para encerrar sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o problema não esteja no .htacess e sim na URL absoluta para acesso do seu backup.xml. Já que usa xampp, é interessante vocẽ criar uma variável gobal chamada $url que recebe o endereço da sua aplicação, exemplo:
`$url = 'localhost/projeto/';` e toda vez que for utilizar é só colocar: `$url."code/backup.xml"`
que provavelmente ele encontrará o arquivo.